# How to show the image of $U$ in $X'$ is dense?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

In Proposition 1.4.18(Chow's Lemma), how to show the image of $U$ in $X'$ is dense?

Comment: which book is it?

Comment: @Yesterdaywasdramatic Algebraic Geometry by Lei Fu.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Because of the above conclusion labeled by red underline, the image of $U$ in $X'$ is dense.

Now I want to know why the following diagram commutes.

[image]